# Angular, Lazy Loading, Inter-Module Dependencies, best practice

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading, angular2-services, angular-router

I have following example application layout:

```
app.module
 |
 |-- dashboard.module                 (lazy loaded)
 |-- dashboard-routing.module         (imported by dashboard.module)
 |-- dashboard.service                (provided by dashboard.module)
 |-- dashboard.component              (depends on dashboard.service)
 |
 |-- notifications.module             (lazy loaded)
 |-- notifications-routing.module     (imported by notifications.module)
 |-- notifications.service            (provided by notifications.module)
 |-- notifications.component          (depends on notifications.service)
 |
 |-- my-notifications-dashboard-widget.component <- this should be added
 |
 |-- ...
```

Every module (`dashboard`, `notifications`, `...`) is getting lazy loaded.

Now I'd like to add some `MyNotificationsDashboardWidgetComponent`, which depends on the `notifications.service`. This widget then should get injected within the `dashboard.service`.

This works well, as long as the provided WidgetComponent is inside the `dashboard.module`. But if I put the component within the lazy loaded `notifications.module`, it of course doesn't work.

Now I'd like to know, how to solve this in a good, **module oriented** way.

My requirements:

- There should only be **one** `notifications.service`, which should be used by `notifications.component` and `my-notifications-dashboard-widget.component`.
- The big modules (`dashboard`, `notifications`) should be lazy loaded.
- The `dashboard.module` shouldn't know anything about the `notifications.module` and / or the `my-notifications-dashboard-widget.component`.

---

### Ideas:

I guess, that I need some eager loaded module, which contains `my-notifications-dashboard-widget.component`. So that this component and its provider is known **before** the `dashboard.module` is getting loaded.

But then I'd have to put the `notifications.service` in this module, too, I guess?!

---

### Some code snippets of the current (non-working) approach:

dashboard.service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {
    constructor(@Inject(DASHBOARD_WIDGET) widgets) {
        // inject all provided widgets
        widgets.forEach(w => console.log(w.type));
    }
}
```

notifications.module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ NotificationsRoutingModule ],
    declarations: [ NotificationsComponent ],
    providers: [
        NotificationsService,
        // this is currently not working, because of lazy loading
        {
            provide: DASHBOARD_WIDGET,
            useValue: {
                type: 'my-notifications'
                component: MyNotificationsDashboardWidgetComponent
            },
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    entryComponents: [ MyNotificationsDashboardWidgetComponent ]
})
export class NotificationsModule { }
```

notifications.component:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class NotificationsComponent {
    constructor(service: NotificationsService) { ... }
}
```

my-notifications-dashboard-widget.component:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class MyNotificationsDashboardWidgetComponent {
    constructor(service: NotificationsService) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that providers at the NgModule level are always registered with the root injector.  There is only one root injector, and any provider registered with the root injector is available application-wide.  The exception to this rule is lazy-loaded modules - lazy loaded modules create their own scoped injector. In other words, any providers registered with a module that is lazy-loaded will not be registered with the root injector.

In order to register providers with the root injector, regardless of whether or not they are lazy-loaded, you should follow the `forRoot` convention.  The idea is that the `forRoot` method returns the module with providers, so that it can be imported by AppModule.

```
@NgModule({
    providers: []
})
export class MyModule {
     static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
         return {
             NgModule: MyModule,
             providers: [
                 MyProvider
             ]
         }
     }
}
```

Note: There is also the `forChild` method you can implement that returns a module without providers.  The intention for this method is so that you can re-use components from a module (including lazy-loaded modules) without actually registering any providers.

Comment: That sounds promising. Could you elaborate on this? If I include `DashboardModule.forRoot()` within my `AppModule`, then I'd have my whole dashboard module loaded. But I guess, I just need the service which injects the providers. And then can later lazy load the rest of the dashboard module (components, etc.)

Comment: Its just a convention.  If you're concerned about registering components unnecessarily (because its only needed from a lazy loaded module) `forRoot` can return any module you like, including an empty module that only has providers.  The `forRoot/forChild` convention exists so that you can register providers with the root injector, even when modules are lazy loaded.

Comment: Thank you. I understand `forRoot/forChild`. But: How should I register `MyNotificationsDashboardWidgetComponent`? I can't call `forChild` from `nofications.module`, because this module is lazy loaded. Or can I?

Comment: Sure, you can. You can import `forChild` from any module, and leverage its components (just make sure `forChild` doesn't return any providers that are intended to be application-wide singletons)

Comment: I'll start again: `notifications.module` is lazy loaded. `dashboard.module` will be eager laded using `forRoot`. When I now have `import: [ DashboardModule.forChild(...) ]` within the lazy loaded `notifications.module`, then it will execute the `forChild` only when I hit the `/notifications` route. That's too late. I must have the `forChild` loaded **before** the `DashboardModule` loads, so the dashboard knows all available widget types (which are provided by other (lazy loaded) modules, i.e. the `notifications.module`)

Comment: For entryComponents, use { provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS... to setup your widget types

Answer (score 2):

In this case you are creating only one widget and in future, you might need more widgets to add.

Solution is, Make anohter shared module and create such component in that module. New shared module will be independent of other modules and all components inside it.

Import shared module in other modules and use it as you want.

Comment: Yeah, of course it is meant for multiple widgets. I just didn't want to pollute the question with 500 additional lines. `...` And what about the services? Maybe you could add some example of the layout?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your inspiration. I've now created a working solution. It still looks a bit strange to me, and some things are a mystery to me, but at least it works.

**Would be nice, if you could leave a comment with some additional information**

app.module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        NotificationModule.forRoot()
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: '/dashboard',
                loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
            },
            {
                path: '/notifications',
                loadChildren: 'app/notification/notification.module#NotificationModule'
            }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

dashboard.module:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [ DashboardService ]
})
export class DashboardModule {
    provideWidget(type: string, component: Type<any>) {
        return [
            {
                provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
                useValue: component,
                multi: true
            },
            {
                provide: DASHBOARD_WIDGET,
                useValue: {
                    type: type,
                    component: component
                },
                multi: true
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

notification.module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NotificationRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        NotificationComponent
    ]
})
export class NotificationModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: NotificationRootModule,
            providers: [ ]
        }
    }
}
```

notification-root.module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TestWidgetComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        NotificationService,
        DashboardModule.provideWidget('TEST', TestWidgetComponent)
    ]
})
export class NotificationRootModule { }
```

### Questions:

I guess I haven't understood `forRoot` and `ModuleWithProviders` completely. I don't understand **why** I have to create a separate `NotificationRootModule` for this to work.

Now the `TestWidgetComponent` and the `NotificationService` are compiled into the app module. Though everything works as expected.

**But:** If I instead use `ngModule: NotificationModule` within `NotificationModule.forRoot()`, then it will put the **whole** module (including `NotificationRoutingModule` and `NotificationComponent`) inside the app module. (I can see that the browser doesn't lazy load anything when opening `/notifications` URL.)

And now I don't know where the `providers` belong. I can put them within `@NgModule({ providers })` of the `NotificationRootModule` or within the `forRoot() { return { providers } }`. It seems to make no difference.

I hope you can enlighten me.

Thanks you!

Comment: The reason you should implement forRoot is so that you can have a singleton service that is shared application wide. If you don't do it, then your lazy loaded module will create its own copy of the service.  This is likely not what you want...  or maybe it is.